# How do I use persist/rehydrate in redux-toolkit?

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

I've setup redux-persist with react-toolkit as suggested in the documentation. Now I need to do some operation on rehydrate ow do I do that? This is what I've tried but not working.

```
...
import { REHYDRATE } from 'redux-persist'
...

const accessControl = createSlice({
  name: 'accessControl',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    loginStart(state: AccessControlState) {
      state.isLoading = true
    },
    loginSucces(state: AccessControlState, action: PayloadAction<LoginResponsePayload>) {
      state.isAuthenticated = true
      state.token = action.payload.access_token
      state.isLoading = false
      state.error = null
    },
    loginFailed(state: AccessControlState, action: PayloadAction<string>) {
      state.isAuthenticated = false
      state.token = ''
      state.isLoading = false
      state.error = action.payload
    },
    logout(state: AccessControlState) {
      state.isAuthenticated = false
      state.token = ''
      state.isLoading = false
      state.error = null
    },
    [REHYDRATE]: (state: AccessControlState) => {
      console.log('in rehydrate')
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`createSlice` uses the keys of the `reducers` object to generate action type constants prefixed by the slice name. In your case, these are strings like `accessControl/loginStart` and `accessControl/loginFailed`.

Your rehydrate reducer isn't called because its action type constant expands to `accessControl/persist/REHYDRATE`, but redux-persist dispatches an action with type `persist/REHYDRATE`.

To handle rehydration, you should instead write your reducer in the [`extraReducers`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#extrareducers) object. These reducers handle external actions and don't generate actions in the slice's `actions` property.

Example:

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { REHYDRATE } from 'redux-persist'

const accessControl = createSlice({
  name: 'accessControl',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    ...
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(REHYDRATE, (state) => {
      console.log('in rehydrate')
    });
  }
})
```